# Rails 4 Migration Error (Can't rake db:migrate) SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sqlite

I've been trying to get the Paperclip gem working. The problem that I was initially running into was that pictures were getting uploaded but not displaying. I then messed around with the database by doing a rake db:rollback to try and fix the error. Now I can't rake db:migrate again because of this error

```
SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: image_file_name: ALTER TABLE "posts" ADD "image_file_name" varchar
```

I've personally went into the migration folder and deleted the file to try and generate a migration again. I've been trying to do rails generate paperclip post image and it does create a migration file, but I'm unable to rake db:migrate.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting a migration file doesn't really rollback the change it made in your database. Your best bet is to:

1. Don't delete the migration but comment out the content of the migration class, and run `rake db:migrate`,

Let's say I have this as my migration file

```
class AddEmailSentToNeeds < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :needs, :email_sent, :boolean ,default: false
  end
end
```

Just comment out the method but leave the class, so it would be:

```
class AddEmailSentToNeeds < ActiveRecord::Migration
  # def change
  #   add_column :needs, :email_sent, :boolean ,default: false
  # end
end
```

This is just a hacky way to tell rails to skip this migration.
OR

2. start from the start so go do, `rake db:drop`, `rake db:create`, and `rake db:migrate`

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried commenting it out, but I get this error when trying to run rake db:migrate   -  NameError: uninitialized constant AddAttachmentImageToPosts

Comment: I did a temporary fix, can't get paperclip working, but I deleted the file and ran migrate again.

Comment: @Wilson: dont comment out the whole content of the migration file. I will edit my post